# eZ Publish 5.x vs Symfony2 - Which and why?

Tags: symfony, content-management-system, ezpublish

I'm in the planning stages for a new project involving eLearning and content management/delivery.

I've dabbled in Symfony2 before and I quite like it's flexibility and extensibility. But I have recently discovered EZ Publish is now running on the Symfony2 stack with version 5.

My question is, what does EZ bring to the table? Will it save me time and money in realising the end product? Or will it ultimately prove to be a hindrance if it is designed to be 'easy' rather than flexible?

Thoughts and suggestions are welcome :) Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how much of platform you will use for your custom logic.

If you will write **most of code using [Symfony components](http://symfony.com/components)** than you can use your bundles interchangeably in Symfony CMF, Symfony Standard Edition or EZ Publish.

If you want working CMS and **write only handful of specific features independent** of CMS functions than you can go with EZ Publish. *But* you still should write your code separated in bundles, so your custom logic is again nicely portable.

If you want to **extend existing CMS features**. Than you might want to go with [Symfony CMF](http://cmf.symfony.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use Symfony CMF, which is the CMS for developers. EZ Publish is not totally migrated to Symfony, so you as a developer will still have to deal with legacy code. Also starting with Symfony Standard Edition to build a CMS you will have to build a lot of tools that are already built into Symfony CMF.

Answer (score 1):

eZ Publish 5 brings you all the features you need when it comes to build a CMS based website. I'd say that 90% of the most important features from eZ Publish 4 have been migrated on Symfony2. You'll also get a really good admin interface.

eZ Publish 5 uses the full stack which makes a big difference when compared to others CMS like Drupal, especially if you need to build business features aside your CMS.

Also, the code quality of eZ Publish 5 is really good and tends to respect the last standards so you'll benefit from this choice one day or another : http://blog.insight.sensiolabs.com/2014/11/04/technical-debt-relevant-projects.html